# android if-statement doesn't work

Tags: android, if-statement

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE;

    private Intent ceec;
    private  EditText cc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);}


    public void sendMessage(View view) 
    {
        ceec = new Intent(this, ToActivity.class);

        cc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);


        String message = cc.getText().toString();
        ceec.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(ceec);
}}
```

And

```
public class ToActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);

        textView.setText(message);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(5,8,100));


        if( message == "hi"){

            textView.setTextSize(80);
        }


        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
        }}


[       if( message == "hi"){

            textView.setTextSize(80);
        } ]
```

It didn't work why? And how to fix it and thank you

Comment: use message.equal("hi") instead of message == "hi"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Comment: you may also use "equalsIgnoreCase"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
message == "hi"
```

You should do:

```
message.equal("hi")
```

Never compare Strings with `==`, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()` method as,

```
if(message.equals("hi")){

    textView.setTextSize(80);
}
else
{
   // do your else stuff
}
```

this should work.